# jQuery UI datepicker not showing week numbers

Tags: jquery-ui, datetime, datepicker, week-number

My jquery UI datepicker is not showing week numbers, even with the showWeek:true option set. Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#startDate').datepicker({ 
      changeMonth: true, 
      changeYear:true, 
      dateFormat: 'd-M-yy', 
      firstDay: 1, 
      showButtonPanel: true, 
      showWeek: true 
  });
});
</script>
<input type='text' name='startDate' id='startDate'>
```

From what I understand, you ONLY need to set the showWeek option to make this work - the weekHeading has a default of 'Wk' and the calculateWeekNumber has a built in ISO week number calculator function.

Also, for some reason the 'Today' button on the button panel is disabled?! Any advice would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact version of jQuery UI that you are using?

Comment: Apologies, using jQuery 1.3.2

Comment: Right - well the jQuery UI is versioned separately from jQuery, and of course there are dependencies bbetween jQuery UI and jQuery.  The datepicker was added in jQuery UI v1.8, which is not yet final, as far as I know.  jQuery UI v1.8 depends on jQuery v1.4.2 .  If you are using jQuery v1.3.2, you need to update to v1.4.2.  Also you need jQuery UI v1.8.

Comment: Apologeez! using jQuery UI 1.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be using jQueryUI v1.7.2.
You need v1.8 to get the `showWeek` option.    I have v1.8rc3 and it works well.

demo: 
http://jsbin.com/eliki